# JavaFX: Drag and Drop absolute positioning

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, positioning

I implemented the drag and drop `ImageView` feature in JavaFX. The issue which I encountered is that when `ImageView` is dropped on the `StackPane`, it gets aligned to the top left corner. Is there a way to make the `ImageView` appear in the exact location where it was dropped (absolute positioning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have set the [`alignment` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#alignmentProperty) of the `StackPane` [or the `ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Pos-) to [`TOP_LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html#TOP_LEFT) you can [set the `margin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setMargin-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Insets-) to position the node:

```
StrackPane pane = ...
...
ImageView iv = ...
...
double posX = ...
double posY = ...
StackPane.setMargin(iv, new Insets(posY, 0, 0, posX));
pane.getChildren().add(iv);
```

However since you seem to look for absolute positioning of children, a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) seems to be the more appropriate layout. (The `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties of the children are not ignored for `Pane`.)